# Can't echo string when used assign operator?

Tags: php

When I run my variable array with foreach,I have found that echo string is not display when using with addition operator.But echo only assign operator can display.What is the reason that can't echo string with using addition operator ?

```
<?php
 $key = 3;
 echo $key+1;echo "<br>";      // 4
 echo "The answer is ".++$key; // The answer is 4
 echo "The answer is ".$key+1; // 1
 //last echo is why can't display string and not getting 4
?>
```

Comment: `echo "The answer is ".($key+1);` and you should get `5`, not `4`

Comment: you are right @MarkBaker , it is 5 by ++

Comment: @MarkBaker, His question is why? So answer is, The `+` operator concat the string. Such as here since first the string "The answer is 1" is created and this is then added to 4 , non-empty non-numeric strings being converted to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're doing a math operation with a string.

`"The answer is ".$key+1` is the same as

```
"The answer is 3" + 1 which equals 1;
```

You need to use () to clearify the scope

```
$key = 3;
"The answer is ".($key+1) === "The answer is 4"
```

Also

```
echo "The answer is ".++$key; // The answer is 4
echo "The answer is ".($key+1); // This would be 5, beause you're incrementing $key by 1 beforehand
```